# Html Show Hide Content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to find an OnClick Function that will work inside of a table.

When the page loads they content needs to be hidden, but given an option either but button or link to show it.

```
<div id="table-container">
<table id="maintable" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1">
  <thead>
  <th class="blk" nowrap>Number</th>
  <th class="blk" nowrap>Original Title</th>
  <th class="blk" nowrap>Translated Title</th>
  </thead>
<tbody>
<td class="lgt"><font size="4">2 Guns&nbsp;</font></td>
<tr><td class="lgt"><font size="4">Two Guns&nbsp;</font></td></tr>
<tr><td class="lgt"><font size="4">English, Spanish&nbsp;</font></td></tr>
<tr><td class="lgt"><font size="4">109&nbsp;</font></td></tr>
```

This is roughly what I am trying to do, is be able to hide

```
<tr><td class="lgt"><font size="4">Two Guns&nbsp;</font></td></tr>
<tr><td class="lgt"><font size="4">English, Spanish&nbsp;</font></td></tr>
<tr><td class="lgt"><font size="4">109&nbsp;</font></td></tr>
```

and or unhide them..

I have tried using the below input..

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function showHide(shID) {
if (document.getElementById(shID)) {
  if (document.getElementById(shID+'-show').style.display != 'none') {
     document.getElementById(shID+'-show').style.display = 'none';
     document.getElementById(shID).style.display = 'block';
  }
  else {
     document.getElementById(shID+'-show').style.display = 'inline';
     document.getElementById(shID).style.display = 'none';
   }
  }
}
</script>
<div id="wrap">
<a href="#" id="example-show" class="showLink" onclick="showHide('example');return false;">See more.</a></p>
<p><a href="#" id="example-hide" class="hideLink" onclick="showHide('example');return false;">Hide this content.</a></p>
</div>
```

All that seems to do is lift the text in the cell of the table, and not the table..

Comment: that was the explanation, where is the code?

Comment: Sorry I haven't ever posted on a site like this, I hope the code I put in was right..

Comment: i don't think the long introduction is necessary... instead, tell people are you trying to hide items on click or what. do you want fading? do you want stuff below to fill up? please describe more!

Comment: I do apologise, I was just trying to make sure I covered all basis as I find it difficult to describe what I am trying to do as I am not really a HTML savvy person. But do have the means to try.

Comment: I have changed my introduction now, also included more coding to try and help with what I am aiming for..

Comment: *"an OnClick Function"* - onclick of what? Are you trying to hide the  body of the table> alone or the whole table?

Comment: I am trying to hide specific Table Rows. The onClick needs to work on lots of different Table Rows. If possible to have a function that once you click one it opens, then when clicks on another it shuts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok someone had helped me with this, and this was the solution to making it work a treat.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('keyup', '#search-box', function(){
    $('#maintable tbody:not(.myContent)').each(function(){
      var movieTitle = $(this).find('td:nth-child(2)').text();
      if (RegExp($('#search-box').val(), 'i').test(movieTitle)) {
        $(this).show();
       } else {
        $(this).hide();
       }
    });
  });
});
</script>

<tr><!-- FIX: Needed to wrap it in a row -->
<td class="lgt" style="height:120px;">Don't Hide</td>
<td class="lgt" style="height:120px;">Don't Hide</td>
<td class="lgt" style="height:120px;">Don't Hide</td>
</tr>   
<tbody class="myContent" style="display:none;">
<tr>
<td colspan="10"class="lgt">Hide This</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="10"class="lgt">Hide This/td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="10"class="lgt">Hide This</td>
</tr><!-- FIX: close row -->
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: Can't seem to get what **exactly** are you trying to do, so I'll try to cover the obvious.
I'm assuming you are coding the HTML yourself and not receiving the output of some server-side script, although that would be the most reasonable.
If you are coding the HTML, that means you can add classes, ids and tags as needed without problems. I would definitely do something entirely different but that would imply more convoluted code.

With multiple sections. A toggle per section:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js'></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('.hidethis').hide();

                $('.toggle').click(function(){
                    section = $(this).attr('data-section');
                    $(section + ' .hidethis').toggle();
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table id='section-1' border="1">
            <caption>SECTION 1</caption>
            <tr>
                <td>Always visible</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="hidethis">
                <td>Hide this</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Always visible</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="hidethis">
                <td>Hide this</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table id='section-2' border="1">
            <caption>SECTION 2</caption>
            <tr>
                <td>Always visible</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="hidethis">
                <td>Hide this</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Always visible</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="hidethis">
                <td>Hide this</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <div class='toggle' data-section='#section-1'>Toggle section 1</div>
        <div class='toggle' data-section='#section-2'>Toggle section 2</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

One toggle per item:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js'></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('.hidethis').hide();

                $('.toggle').click(function(){
                    $('.hidethis', $(this).parent()).toggle();
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table id='section-1' border="1">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <table>
                        <tr class='toggle'>
                            <td>
                                Always visible<br/>
                                <small>Toggle this</small>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="hidethis">
                            <td>Hide this</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>
                    <table>
                        <tr class='toggle'>
                            <td>
                                Always visible<br/>
                                <small>Toggle this</small>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="hidethis">
                            <td>Hide this</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>                   

        </table>

    </body>
</html>
```

In this case, notice that in order to not over-complicate the jQuery code, you'll need some kind of container that parent both title and expandable content.

Comment: That would work for only one specific section.. What I would need is to be able to make it hide per Class Name, that is what I have found is the most likely option.. class="hidethis1" class="hidethis2" and so on, then anything in those classes will hide or show upon being clicked

Answer (score 0):

After much more searching about, I found this...

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function toggle() {
 if( document.getElementById("hidethis").style.display=='none' ){
   document.getElementById("hidethis").style.display = '';
 }else{
   document.getElementById("hidethis").style.display = 'none';
 }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<span onClick="toggle();">toggle</span><br /><br />

<table border="1">
<tr>
<td>Always visible</td>
</tr>
<tr id="hidethis">
<td>Hide this</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Always visible</td>
</tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

It worked a treat, the problem I found with it, was I couldn't work out how to make it do more than just 1 row.. But in the other posts someone mentioned using..

```
<tbody>
```

So I did over the ones I needed.. Now I have included a button and I am done with it :)
Thanks for your help though

Comment: Ok, so I thought I was done, but I am not. All this code does is makes it so one works. How would I make it so I can have unlimited amount??